# haskell binary tree path function

Tags: function, haskell, path, binary-tree

I am trying to define a function which will return the list of all
paths through a given binary tree.
I have the following functions defined already:

```
data BTree a = Leaf a | Node a (BTree a) (BTree a)
     deriving (Show,Eq)

paths :: BTree a -> [[a]] 
paths (Leaf a) = [[]]
paths (Node x left right) = map (x:) (paths left ++ paths right)
```

With this function I have the following results for example: 
`[[5,4],[5,4],[5,3],[5,3]]` . But I was supposed to have as a result the output `[[5,4,1],[5,4,2],[5,3,3],[5,3,4]]`. 
Do anyone know why i dont get the 3rd value?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your `BTree` type is:

```
data BTree a = Leaf a | Node a (BTree a) (BTree a)
```

Note that, unlike a list, it is never empty: both the leaves and the nodes contain values of type `a`. That being so, if you have a case in `paths` that always produces empty lists, such as...

```
paths (Leaf a) = [[]]
```

... you are necessarily throwing values away. What you want instead is:

```
paths :: BTree a -> [[a]] 
paths (Leaf a) = [[a]]
paths (Node x left right) = map (x:) (paths left ++ paths right)
```